# Restricted to play on embedded youtube - ionic web mobile app

Tags: cordova, google-chrome-extension, ionic-framework, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am creating a mobile app with ionic framework. When I use embedded youtube `<iframe>` on my chrome browser, it works fine. When I try out my app on my iphone 6 with Ionic View app, I enter the following problem.
I see that there are many posts on stackoverflow explaining how to bypass the restriction. However, my case is different. I cannot access all the browser setting on my iphone. How can I bypass this restriction?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does the video play in the browser?  If it doesn't play in the browser, it won't play in the device either. It's a youtube restriction

Comment: The video plays in browser, but it doesn't play on phone.

Comment: Looks like youtube or this specific channel doesn't allow calls from localhost or apps . The only solution that works is "Embed the youtube video in your website page and then embed the website page into ionic app iframe". Also, did you try playing videos from any other channels?

Comment: Other music is fine, I think this is is from Vevo. Is there no other way to go around it?

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I am seeing the same issue.